# MongoDB query to get count of array values for specific groups

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to achieve a group which tells me the count of occurrence of color and the entity count corresponding to each color.

I have written a query, But this is giving me twice the count because of unwind i guess.

My Query :

```
db.message.aggregate([
{$unwind: '$entities'},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "color": "$color",
        "entities" :"$entities"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.color",
    "count": { "$sum": "$count" },
    "entities": { 
        "$push": { 
            "entity": "$_id.entities",
            "count": "$count"
        },
    }

}}
])
```

Database Message Data :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c55f99abf6dc481ccfa7f67"),
"color" : "Red",
"channel" : "google",
"content" : "red color",
"entities" : [ 
    "a", 
    "b"
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c57f0a0bf6dc44424e8d371"),
"color" : "Red",
"channel" : "google",
"content" : "red color",
"entities" : [ 
    "a", 
    "b"
]
},{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c5947a4bf6dc462603d87da"),
"color" : "Blue",
"channel" : "google",
"content" : "yo yo",
"entities" : [ 
    "a", 
    "b"
]
 },
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c6151b9bf6dc4bee8dac8c9"),
"color" : "Blue",
"handle" : "IBM",
"channel" : "twitter",
"content" : "yo yo",
"entities" : [ 
    "a", 
    "b",
    "c"
]
}
```

(EDITED) I am Expecting the following Output :

```
{
"color" : "Red",
"count" : 2,
"entities" : [ 
    {
        "entity" : "a",
        "count" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "entity" : "b",
        "count" : 2
    }
    ]
},
{
"color" : "Blue",
"count" : 2,
"entities" : [ 
    {
        "entity" : "c",
        "count" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "entity" : "b",
        "count" : 2
    }, 
    {
        "entity" : "a",
        "count" : 2
    }
]
}
```

Please Help!.

Comment: `classification` is not an array field. How can you use `$unwind` with it?

Comment: Ya , even if i remove that it  makes no difference

Comment: Could you post the expected output as well

Comment: I have edited my question for the output that i am expecting , Thanks .